# Marcar y sumar. React

Tags: reactjs, materialize

Espero que esten bien.

Necesito un poco de ayuda en react, soy relativamente nuevo en react. El problema es el siguiente.

Tengo una card hecha con materialize y en el contenido tengo 4 checkbox. Quiero que cuando se marque un checkbox se vaya sumando a una cantidad numerica de un objeto que tengo, en este caso un carro.

Aqui el codigo de mi componente.

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';

class CheckBox extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            Puertas:'',
            Neon:'',
            Ventanas:'',
            Neumaticos:'',
        }
        this.handleCheckBox = this.handleCheckBox.bind(this);
    }

    handleCheckBox(e){
        if(e === true){
            console.log('true');
        }else{
            console.log('false')
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div className="container">
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>this.handleCheckBox(e.target.value) } />
                    <span>Puertas</span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span>Ventanas</span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span>Neon</span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span>Neumaticos</span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
        )
    }
  }

export default CheckBox
```

Aqui estoy intentado que me imprima en la consola cuando este activo o no.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias tratar colocandole un nombre a tus checkboxes relativo al de tu objeto, algo asi como:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Puertas" onChange={this.handleCheckBox} />
```

Luego en el handler podrias solo hacer algo como esto:

```
handleCheckBox = e => { //asi no tienes que hacer bind en el constructor
    if(e.target.value === true){
     let name = e.target.name
     let carPart = this.state[name]
     this.setState({[name]: carPart + 1})
        console.log('true');
    }else{
        console.log('false')
    }
}
```

No lo he probado, pero esto deberia darte una idea de como solucionarlo, espero haberte ayudado.